# the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used (RE: miceadds, MIDS)

Tags: r

I'm working on hot deck imputation in R using the hot.deck package and testing it out by following the example described here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hot.deck/vignettes/Using_Hot_Deck_Data.pdf

The data set is data(isq99).  I'm going to skip the other variables that are created and just discuss the hot deck results. Here is *exactly* what I've done:

```
library(hot.deck)
data(isq99)
out <- hot.deck(isq99, sdCutoff=3, IDvars=c("IDORIGIN","YEAR"))
```

I'm stuck on combining the results using the mids technique on p. 3 (2.3 "Using mids"--I know it says out$imputations but that's if you convert to amelia):

```
library(miceadds)
out.mids <- datalist2mids(out$data)
```

When I do this, I get the following error message:

```
Warning message:
In if (class(dat.list) %in% "imputationList") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Here's what happens if I look at the structure of the original hot deck results:

```
            Length   Class  Mode   
data               5 mi     list   
affinity    14775370 -none- numeric
donors          4661 -none- list   
draws           4661 -none- list   
max.emp.aff     4661 -none- numeric
max.the.aff     4661 -none- numeric
```

I have no idea why it's rejecting out$data (which as expected has 5 versions of multiple imputation data)--is there something that I should have known about reducing the length into a single set first?

Any help is appreciated. Apologies re: formatting or if I have forgotten anything - please let me know what else you need.

thanks

Comment: Perhaps you want an `any` or `all` in the boolean in the if statement

Comment: @Carl is it possible to change that? The if statement is from the package itself. The actual R code described above is exactly what I've done, as described in the linked paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a bug on the part of the *miceadds* package/function author, not anticipating that an object can have more than one class (or just wrote the `%in%` call backwards) and not checking the object given in the `dat.list` argument beforehand. Either way, `%in%` is not the proper way to check classes.  CRAN source is [datalist2mids.R](https://github.com/cran/miceadds/blob/master/R/datalist2mids.R). I would file a bug report using the email address in  `maintainer("miceadds")`.

Comment: I have written to the maintainer per your suggestion and will mark this as answer as soon as I get a response, or if no response, will mark in a few days.

Comment: Better late than never: the maintainer did write back asap, and it's a warning that does not throw a bug. Conversion to mids object actually does work, but maintainer also noted he would modify the function in subsequent miceadds versions to avoid warning message.

Answer (score 1):

Per @Richard's suggestion, I did write to the maintainer of miceadds and he replied back ASAP which I greatly appreciated.

Turns out that this is just a warning, not a bug, and that the mids object really was produced. This was a total noob oversight on my part. The miceadds author did note that he might change/remove the warning in future versions of the package.